# how to add all values in an json object which is hvaing differnet keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

how to add all values in json object, below i have given object. but here values are coming as string in object.Here object contains different keys.

```
var a = { a: "0", b: "2", c: "3" };
```

and

```
result = 5
```

Comment: your question is about a simple topic in javascript, please remove node.js and json tag from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the sum of all values of an object

```js
var a = {
  a: "0",
  b: "2",
  c: "3"
};

const result = Object.values(a).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr ={a:"0",b:"2",c:"3"}

 // We first need all valus in object as array 
 // ["0","2", "3"]
let arrValue =  Object.values(arr);


// to get a single value we can use reduce 
// while reducing we can also convert string numebr to number by simply adding a + before them.


let total = arrValue.reduce((total,value) => { total += (+value); return total }, 0);
console.log(total);
```